# How redis pub/sub internally works?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have few queries regarding how it internally works :

1.) Redis cluster does Hash slot based uniform partitioning . If we create a channel say C1 and its created in node1 then whatever we push in the channel will always get store in C1 in node1 of redis cluster . My understanding is correct ?
2.) If total size of messages in single channel exceeds node capacity then will it split elements in the channel to multiple nodes in redis cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

Pub/Sub isn't keyspace-related so cluster partitioning doesn't apply to it.

WRT 1: Pub/Sub in a cluster is a full-mesh, so any node getting a `PUBLISH` broadcasts it in the cluster bus to all other nodes. All nodes then send the published message to their respective subscribers (if any)

WRT 2: There is no maximal channel capacity - messages are sent immediately as they are published.